# Unable to get email-ext.hpi to work in hudson

Tags: hudson, hudson-plugins, email-ext

I have just setup hudson and have begun playing around with it.

1. I have downloaded the email-ext.hpi into the the folder $HUDSON_HOME\plugins
2. I have restarted hudson post-step1 ( i am following this manual method as i am unable to use (for proxy setting reasons) the automatic way of installing plugins via the "Manage hudson" page.
3. I dont see any errors when hudson starts. In fact i see the line
   INFO: Started all plugins

BUT:
When i start a project configuration page, I do not see the promised option "Editable Email Notification".

FYI:
1. I am able to setup and run few basic test builds and they run fine.
2. I am also able to configure and receive the default hudson emails for failures and subsequent successes.(This confirms the SMTP settings) 
3. I was also aboe to setup the subversion tag hpi in the same way as detailed above and that works fine as well!

What am i missing? Thanks in advance for any help!

EXTRA INFO:
Hudson version - 1.379 running on Windows XP

Answer (score 0):

OK - i figured out a workaround (although i still need to dig into why this is a problem). Recording here for anyone else tha tmay face this issue.

The plugin when copied into the $HUDSON_HOME\plugin was somehow not really being activeated/recognized. But when i copied it over also to C:\Documents and Settings\mylogin.hudson\plugins and restarted hudson service, voila! it worked.

If anyone knows why this might have occured, kindly record it here for reference. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To install a plugin you should use the easy route. In Hudson, go to 'Manage Hudson' -> 'Manager Plugins' -> 'Advanced' (its a tab) and use the 'upload plugin' option.

Than follow the instructions. Usually you have to restart Hudson to actually get the plugin.

Way saver than messing around with the file system. In general the approach you had should have been correct, but there seems to be an issue with your $HUDSON_HOME. Have a look at the "Manage Hudson" -> "Configure System" page. What is the Hudson Home directory displayed on the top of the page? I don't know what Hudson does if it can't access the Home Directory? My assumption is here that Hudson runs as a service with a user account rather than the local system account and that you used a different account to copy the hpi file.

Comment: Thanks! As you can see from my question, this cant be the root cause. I am able to run other builds fine, and i see the workspaces getting created fine within the hudson home area, so this is only really specific to the plugins. Also the reason i followed the manual method and not the "Manage Hudson route" is listed above in my question as well ;-) In any case, ive sorted the issue, i just would like to know why this is specific to hudson plugins.

Comment: @Critical Skill: If you use the 'upload File' option, you can install your **already downloaded file**. Therefore there should be no proxy issue at all.

Comment: What binary do you start when Hudson gets started? Could it be that the binary that gets started is in the users home?

Answer (score 0):

Install Maven Legacy and Maven3 plugins .

Comment: You should add some resources to backup your claim or expand more about your answer.